# Cocos2d-x crash when load CSB file

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm using `Cocos2d-x 3.2` to load the empty scene created with `CocoStudio 2`.

Here is what I did:

- First, I create new project with CocoStudio 2
- CocoStudio created the default `MainScene.csd` file
- I export the project to Xcode project via `File` > `Publish` > `Publish to Xcode project`
- I open up the Xcode project and go to `HelloWorldScene.cpp`, include the `cocostudio.h`, import the `res` folder created by `CocoStudio`, then put the below code in `HelloWorldScene::init()` function:

```cpp
auto mainScene = SceneReader::getInstance()->createNodeWithSceneFile("MainScene.csb");
this->addChild(mainScene);
```

- Then I run, and the app crashed (see attached image)

[image: strange crash]

I have no idea why it crashed! Is there anybody got this problem?

And please let me know if is this the right way to load `CSB` scene from `CocoStudio`? If not, what is the right way?

I have read somewhere, they're using `CSLoader` but I cannot find this in version `3.2`.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the problem.

It's just because I'm using `cocos2d-x v3.2` and `CocoStudio 2`

`CocoStudio 2` only work with `cocos2d-x v3.3`, and if you want to use `cocos2d-x v3.2`, you should use `CocoStudio 1.6` (on Windows) or `CocoStudio 1.0` (on Mac)

For me, I upgraded to `cocos2d-x v3.3rc0`

Too bad, they give us the download link for `cocos2d-x v3.2` and `CocoStudio 2` on home page.